# discord.py как сделать ограничения у определённого пользователя в канале

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, бот

этот код должен убирать разрешение пользователя на отправку сообщений в определённый канал.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать дополнительную роль, при которой нельзя отправлять сообщение и через бота её выдавать.

Прикладываю "лайфхак", как комфортнее работать с библиотекой discord, так как она недостаточно типизирована, а чтобы IDE лучше подсказывала, вручную типизируй объекты, опираясь на документацию.

А также не забудь добавить в функции дополнительные декораторы на права использования, в этом примере команды могут использовать все участники сервера и проверь, что у бота есть права изменять роли участников.

```
bot = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")


@bot.command()
async def give_role(ctx: commands.Context, member_id: int):
    mute_role = 123  # роль, которая блокирует отправку сообщений  
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(mute_role)  # получение объекта роли
    member: discord.Member = ctx.guild.get_member(member_id)  # получение объекта пользователя
    await member.add_roles(role) # добавить роль
    
    
@bot.command()
async def remove_role(ctx: commands.Context, member_id: int):
    mute_role = 123  # роль, которая блокирует отправку сообщений  
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(mute_role)  # получение объекта роли
    member: discord.Member = ctx.guild.get_member(member_id)  # получение объкета пользователя
    await member.remove_roles(role)  # убрать роль
    

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason="причина не указана"):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="mute") #название роли
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    await member.send(f"Вас замьютили на сервере {ctx.guild.name}\nПричина: {reason}\nВремя мута: {time} минут") #отправка сообщения в лс


    await member.remove_roles(mute_role)```
````